# R how to read XML file

Tags: xml, r

I have a XML file as the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<s_observation>
  <observation datetime="2014-09-01T00:00:00Z">
    <station id="06179" lat="49.44700" lon="18.78123">
      <precipitation>0.0</precipitation> 
    </station>
    <station id="06200" lat="49.29720" lon="18.78431">
      <precipitation>0.0</precipitation> 
      <discharge>10.450</discharge> 
    </station>
 </observation>
</s_observation>
```

I'm able to get correctly the value of discharge and precipitation by the following command:

```
tavola1 = xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(data1,"//s_observation/observation/station"))
```

I don't know how to get the value of "observation datetime" and "station id".
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this `xml` file is in your working directory and named `test.xml`, the following should illustrate various features/functionality of the `XML` package and how to obtain `observation datetime` and `station id` from the various nodes:

```
library(XML)

doc <- xmlTreeParse("test.xml")
root <- xmlRoot(doc)
obs_child <- xmlChildren(root)

xmlAttrs(obs_child[[1]])
#               datetime 
# "2014-09-01T00:00:00Z" 

xmlGetAttr(obs_child[[1]], "datetime")
# [1] "2014-09-01T00:00:00Z"

stations <- xmlChildren(obs_child[[1]])
xmlAttrs(stations[[1]])
#     id        lat        lon 
# "06179" "49.44700" "18.78123" 
xmlGetAttr(stations[[1]], "id")
# [1] "06179"

xmlAttrs(stations[[2]])
#      id        lat        lon 
# "06200" "49.29720" "18.78431" 
xmlGetAttr(stations[[2]], "id")
# [1] "06200"
```

Comment: I did what you suggested me and works! Just another clarification if I need the number of stations, in order to set a "for cicle" for example, how can I get it? Thanks!